# PHP MySQL Trouble With the Syntax

Tags: php, mysql

Need your advice about my PHP MySQL syntax. I work hard with that, but still facing problem with the query and the error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$bagianWhere = ""' at line 1: $bagianWhere = ""

You can see my demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bde161/1)

Answer (score 0):

If "bagianWhere" is empty, the SQL query becomes invalid with an orphan "WHERE" at the end. You can do

> $bagianWhere = "1 = 1";

at the top to counter for that.

Also get rid of "$bagianWhere .= " and make it "$bagianWhere = "

Also the error you are mentioning here is from SQL Fiddle, as you have put in PHP code in there. Can you run the PHP on your web server and show us the error you get.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply... The error is : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: @NoReply `echo $query;` after the query is made and post it here.